# How to continue with last screen when i exit or app is crashed on Android with Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, savestate, navcontroller

I'm trying to create something for the Android app using Compose and navigation, to make it possible to continue with the last screen I was showing to the user if an app crashed or been killed by the user.

I was searching for a solution on Google, and I found the way with sharedPreferences but I think it wouldn't help me, is there any other way to do that?

Comment: You need something that will be able to "remember" that the app was killed, so shared preferences or holding it in a file of some sort would be (as I'm aware) your only option

Comment: i was wondering , in my case , each of the screens have their own viewmodels , so if i just save in shared preferences some value every-time i enter each of that screens , but then to handle that option would be some tricky , because i have too much screens , that's why i'm asking , maybe there is some better options to handle that

Comment: but anyways thank you !

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that's the only way, saving and reading from the shared preferences isn't really costly nor time consuming, so it should work fine (I believe)

Comment: thank you very much , i've started implementing this

Comment: now i have problems with navigation and back button , when i continue with the screen i last used , back button doesnot work ....